# You have an error in your SQL syntax,t syntax to use near 'name.ek_product_description LIKE 'f%'' at line 1

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  category_id.ek_category_description, 
  name.ek_category_description, 
  name.ek_product_description 
FROM ek_category_description JOIN ek_product_description 
WHERE category_id.ek_category_description 
  NOT IN( SELECT DISTINCT parent_id FROM ek_category) 
  AND 
  name.ek_category_description,
  name.ek_product_description LIKE '$searchvalue%'
```

Comment: it's missing the where clause on name.ek_category_description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Probably, you need to correct the where clause by ending it.
2. Field names should follow the table name.

   ```
   SELECT DISTINCT
     ek_category_description.category_id,
     ek_category_description.name as name1, 
     ek_product_description.name  as name2 
   FROM ek_category_description JOIN ek_product_description 
   WHERE ek_category_description.category_id 
     NOT IN( SELECT DISTINCT parent_id FROM ek_category) 
     AND 
     ((ek_category_description.name LIKE '$searchvalue%') OR
     (ek_product_description.name LIKE '$searchvalue%'))
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on your logic, but a missing coma was between `name.ek_category_description,name.ek_product_description`

Possible fix?:

```
SELECT DISTINCT category_id.ek_category_description,
 name.ek_category_description,name.ek_product_description 
 FROM ek_category_description JOIN ek_product_description 
 WHERE category_id.ek_category_description NOT IN( 
  SELECT DISTINCT parent_id FROM ek_category) 
 AND (name.ek_category_description LIKE '$searchvalue%') 
 AND (name.ek_product_description LIKE '$searchvalue%')
```